# Send Locust HTML report to s3 bucket

Tags: load-testing, locust

I am running my locust tests on an ec2 instance and wanted to check if there is a way to send the results over to an s3 bucket once the test run finishes.

Is there a folder on the ec2 instance where locust saves the .html report file or how do we go about this.

The ec2 instance has locust installed and i just run the locust command to execute the test, no docker container involved.

Answer (score 1):

Too generate html:
locust -f script.py --headless -u 1 -r 1 --run-time 15s --html=test1.html

You can do so by running the following commands:
aws s3 cp test1.html s3://your-bucket test2.html --acl bucket-owner-full-control